# Conditional Word Document Auto Generation from an Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I want Word to take in data from a spreadsheet (Excel) and check each cell for its value. If its value is a specific one, then Word presents (prints, puts in, whatever you care to call it) a corresponding paragraph.

I've been Googling for hours, to no avail. As far as I can tell, what I need is a backwards, conditional Mail Merge for word; some program that can generate a paragraph from essentially a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_ExcelCalcFromWord()

Dim oExcel                      As Excel.Application
Dim oBook                       As Excel.Workbook

Dim sString                     As String
Dim oParagraph                  As Word.Paragraph


Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("U:/Book1.xlsx")
oExcel.Visible = True

sString = oBook.Sheets("Errors").Range("A1")

If sString = "Haha" Then
    Set oParagraph = ThisDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oParagraph.Range.Text = sString
End If

End Sub
```

You have to reference the Microsoft Excel Object Library before you can call Excel objects.
You can further customize this code the way you need it (create more paragraph objects, add formatting to it etc...)